# Where can I learn about apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, windows, apache-2.4, mac

I use apache web server for web development in python. The biggest problem I face with apache is setting up the environment. I can't understand thing like what is difference between `/etc/apache2 and /private/etc/apache2`. Also, things like `/etc/private/apache2/httpd.conf and /etc/private/apache2/original/httpd.conf`. Are they both same? Which one to change?

Everytime I land in some set up problem and I keep on following instruction written by users like an idiot.

Also, I don't understand how can apache point to custom directories(which files needed to be changed) and localhost would open up documents from that Directory(~Sites).

I want to learn all about apache environment. What all directories mean? Which are the important file and which aren't?

I went to apache docs but they are very messed up. Looks like it would take me years to read all of it. Can any one help me to find a nice startup article. Some tutorials?

Comment: As to the configuration files, that's your OS/Distro's configuration management choices. The stock httpd doesn't have all those extra directories and files; it's a much simpler layout (slightly more complicated to configure sometimes). As for the rest, have you tried the [Apache animal book](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0596002033)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing how you have a /private/etc directory I guess you're running Apache on MacOS X (please avoid putting linux windows and mac tags at the same time).

[This article](https://donatstudios.com/PHP-in-OS-X-Yosemite) should help you set up apache (ignore PHP related stuff).

Basically, start by learning what httpd.conf file you should edit and look at Virtual Host/DocumentRoot.

Having said that, you probably could use a very simple dev server or framework if you want to try your hand at python web-dev. I usually use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Comment: i use django not flask :)